# Get PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_DATA in ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, contacts

I built a contact list and I'm trying to add the contact's photos to it, I managed to get a Contact PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_DATA but I cannot figure how to load it to an ImageView.

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) itemLayout.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
final String photoUri = cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_DATA);
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use ImageView.setImageURI()

> public void setImageURI (Uri uri)
>
> Sets the content of this ImageView to the specified Uri.
>
> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can
>   cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using
>   setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or
>   setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.

for example

```
String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
if (uri != null) {
    Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(uri);
    iv_object_contact.setImageURI(photoUri);
}
else {
    iv_object_contact.setImageResource(res_default_contact);
}
```

Comment: Hi Toon, your code worked but I had to check if "uri" was null before parsing it or it would return an error. Does it make sense to you? I edited it in the answer

Comment: Dear Liso, you need to check if it is null, otherwise if system try to setImageURI as NULL it would crash

Comment: I might type something mistake since I just type in notepad without check, if you found something wrong, please fix it for me :)

Comment: Ok thanks! You were checking if photoUri was null, I changed it so it checks if uri is null before trying to parse it. Doing it without validating it provoked an exception